# How do I turn a card/badge between 180 degrees on the y-axis back to front by tab on smart devices?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Stack: HTML, CSS, TailwindCSS, Chrome- Safari- Desktop and iPhone 12 Mini, iOS17.

I've written some code (pasted below) that I can turn a badge by 180 degrees, if I hover/click on it, to the back side.

On Chrome and Safari browser on desktop it works on all view port sizes by hovering with the mouse over it. I like it that way, if the page is displayed on a desktop/laptop screen.

The problem I have occurs on the smart phone.

In Chrome on iPhone 12 Mini, I can tab on a badge and it turns to the back side.
If I tab again on it, nothing happens. It turns only back to the front side, if I tab on another badge or on the background of the page.

In Safari on iPhone 12 Mini, I have to tab and hold a badge, to turn it on the back side.
It only turns back to the front side if I tab and hold another badge or if I do tab and hold on the background of the page.

How do I avoid this behavior on smart devices in that way, that I can turn a badge to the back side and front side only by tabbing on it?

HTML/TailwindCSS:

```html
<section class="mt-8">
  <div class="relative badge opacity-80 text-emerald-950 text-sm">
    <div class="badge__side--front bg-emerald-200 rounded-full h-14 w-14 flex justify-center items-center ease-in-out duration-1000 ">
      <h2>Foo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="badge__side badge__side--back absolute top-0 bg-emerald-200 rounded-full h-14 w-14 flex justify-center items-center ease-in-out duration-1000">
      <h2>bar</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
.badge__side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.badge__side--back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.badge:hover .badge__side--front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.badge:hover .badge__side--back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```